# I want to replace outlier instead of completely removing it... Any Suggestion?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have data-set in which one column has outlier and these outlier somehow dependent on one more column which has 12 different categories.

So, I want to replace these outlier with mean of those categories.

for example:

column A has market_01, market_02, ..., market_12 and

column B has int values 984, 678, 1326, 887, ....., 710, .....

so, here, I want to replace 1326 outlier value with respect to its corresponding market_02.mean() rather than simply values.mean()

[image]

Comment: Paste your data as text rather than an image @nish8690

Answer (score 1):

Try:

via `mask()` + `groupby()`+`transform()`

```
#Firstly find mean:
m=df.groupby('market')['values'].transform('mean').round(2)
#Finally replace outlier:
df['values']=df['values'].mask(df['values'].eq(1326),m)
```

OR

via `np.where()` with `groupby()`+`transform()`:

```
m=df.groupby('market')['values'].transform('mean').round(2)
df['values']=np.where(df['values'].eq(1326),m,df['values'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Calculate the mean of the values corresponding to the market.

```
mean_val = df[df['market'] = 'market_02']['values'].mean()
```

Step 2: Now replace all values greater (or equal to) the value that you believe is outlier with the above calculated mean.

```
df['values'] = df['values'].apply(lambda x: mean_val if x >= mean_val else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Pratik and @Anurag for your answers.

I have solved this by below approach: By this way my all outlier are replaced.

```
t = df.groupby('market').values
df['values'] = (
    df.values.where(
        t.transform('quantile', q=0.75) > df.values,
        t.transform('median')))
```